# Sesion Activa en ionic Framework (Sqlite)

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estoy utilizando en mi app base de datos sqlite para guardar el estado de la sesion e informacion de un usuario. Lo que estoy realizando me ha funcionado pero tengo un problema:
Al momento de validar si el estado de la sesion es activa hago que se presente la vista html correspondiente al usuario hasta alli todo bien, pero  cuando cierro mi app y la vuelvo a ejecutar PRIMERO SE MUESTRA LA VISTA DE LOGIN y despues de 1 O 2 segundos se muestra LA VISTA DEL USUARIO.

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que cuando ejecute la aplicacion se muestre directo la vista del usuario. En si lo que deseo es que no se muestre la vista de login a menos que el estado de la sesion no sea activa

Este es mi codigo:
App.js (Todo este proceso lo hago aquí)

```
var db = null;//paso 1 BD
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite,$state) {//paso 2 agrego cordovaSqlite
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      //creo la tabla tutoria
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: 'tuto.db' });//paso 3 creo  la BD
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tutoria (id integer primary key, estado text, rolUs text, pNombre text, Inicial text, sNombre text, pApellido text, sApellido text, cedula text)");
      //fin creo la tabla tutoria
      //comprobar sesion
      var query = "SELECT * FROM tutoria";
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query).then(function(result) {
        for ( j=0; j < result.rows.length; j++) { 
          if(result.rows.item(j).estado=="Sesion_Activa" && result.rows.item(j).rolUs=="docente"){
            $state.go('tabs.perfilDocente'); //aqui hago que se muestra la vista del docente
          }else{
            if(result.rows.item(j).estado=="Sesion_Activa" && result.rows.item(j).rolUs=="estudiante"){
              $state.go('tabsEst.perfilEstudiante'); // aca muestro la vista del estudiante dependiendo del rol
            }
          }               
        }
      });
      //fin comprobar sesion
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
//VISTAS
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {  
  $stateProvider
    //Login de la APP
    .state('login',{
      cache: false,
      url:'/login',
      templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    // PADRE DE VISTAS TABS DOCENTE
    .state('tabs',{
      cache: false,
      url:'/Gtuto',
      abstract:true,
      templateUrl:'templates/tabs.html'
    })
    //Hijos de TABS
    .state('tabs.perfilDocente', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/perfil',
      views:{
        'perfil-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/perfilDocente.html',
          controller:'SalirCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.CompDocente', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentes',
      views:{
        'componentes-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/CompDocente.html',
          controller:'DocenteCtrl'
        }
      }
    })    
    .state('tabs.ListaTutoDocente', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentes/:nom_coe',
      views:{
        'componentes-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/ListaTutoDocente.html',
          controller:'DocenteCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.CrearTutoria', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentes/:nom_coe/:paralelo',
      views:{
        'componentes-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/CrearTutoria.html',
          controller:'DocenteCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.ContEdicionTuto', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentes/:Nom_coe/EdicionTutorias/:id',
      views:{
        'componentes-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/ContEdicionTuto.html',
          controller:'DocenteCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.comentarios', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentes/:componentesId/:c/:f/:d',
      views:{
        'componentes-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/comentarios.html',
          controller:'DocenteCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.participantes', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentes/:componentesId/:c/:f/:d/:e',
      views:{
        'componentes-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/participantes.html',
          controller:'DocenteCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.notDoc', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/notificaciones',
      views:{
        'notificaciones-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/NotDoc.html'
        }
      }
    })
    // PADRE DE VISTAS TABSEST ESTUDIANTE
    .state('tabsEst',{
      cache: false,
      url:'/Gtuto',
      abstract:true,
      templateUrl:'templates/tabsEst.html'
    })
    //Hijos de TABSEST
    .state('tabsEst.perfilEstudiante', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/perfilEst',
      views:{
        'perfil-tabsEst':{
          templateUrl:'templates/perfilEstudiante.html',
          controller:'SalirCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabsEst.CompEstudiante', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentesEst',
      views:{
        'componentes-tabsEst':{
          templateUrl:'templates/CompEstudiante.html',
          controller:'AlumnoCtrl'
        }
      }
    })    
    .state('tabsEst.ListaTutoEstudiante', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentesEst/:nombre',
      views:{
        'componentes-tabsEst':{
          templateUrl:'templates/ListaTutoEstudiante.html',
          controller:'AlumnoCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabsEst.notificaciones', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/notificacionesEst',
      views:{
        'notificaciones-tabsEst':{
          templateUrl:'templates/NotEst.html'
        }
      }
    })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})
//FIN VISTAS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón por la que te esta pasando eso es simple.

- Tienes 15 rutas pero ninguna esta enlazada con la url `'/'`
- Tienes una configuración que dice `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');`

Esto significa que tu aplicación **siempre** usará la el estado `login` como su pantalla inicial ya que la url por defecto es `'/'` y luego navegará a `'/login'` siguiendo la configuración que le pusiste. Para evitar que se vea la pantalla del login tienes tres opciones

1. Usar un [splash-screen](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/splashscreen/) y ocultarlo después que hayas verficado si la sesión esta activa o no.

   ```
   $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query).then(function(result) {
       // verifico que estoy logueado y navego a la vista correspondiente
       $cordovaSplashscreen.hide(); 
   });
   ```

   Esta opción solo te funcionará en un móvil y no cuando estés testeando tu aplicación en el navegador
2. Usar una vista vacía enlazada a la url `'/'` y en un controller pruebas si la sesión esta activa, desde ahí haces la redirección

   *definición de rutas*

   ```
    $stateProvider
        .state('start',{
            url:'/',
            controller: 'StartCtrl'
         })
   ```

   *controller*

   ```
   angular.module('app')
       .controller('StartCtrl', function() {
           $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query).then(function(result) {
              // determina si tienes una sesión activa
              if (session) {
                  $state.go('usuario');
              } else {
                  $state.go('login')
              }
           });
       });
   ```

   Con esta opción tienes un controlador extra en tu app cuya única función es verificar que estés logueado.
3. Usar el evento [`$stateChangeStart`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) hacer un `event.preventDefault()` y redireccionar a la vista del usuario en caso que estés logueado

   ```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
        if (toState === 'login' && session) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('usuario');
        }
    });
   ```

   El manejador de eventos es sincrónico y estás usando promises para obtener tus datos `$cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query).then(...)` por lo que esta variante **es posible que no te funcione**.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por su respuesta...Con respecto al splash screen debe ser uno diferente al que viene por defecto en ionic?? 
en caso de decirme que sí. Puedo implementar $ionicloading?

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno El splash screen que te digo es nativo del sistema operativo. Necesitas instalar este plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen y seguir las instrucciones que hay en ng-cordova. Si quieres poner un $ionicLoading tienes que usar la variante 2, un controller inicial y especificarle una vista con `templateUrl` en la definición del estado. Básicamente haces una vista inicial que simula ser un splash screen. Ahí puedes poner lo que quieras.

Comment: he puesto en practica lo q me ha dicho .... pero podria revisarme lo q he hecho al parecer una parte no se ejecuta...he agregado como respuesta..si es tan amable de revisarme

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno El problema está en el ciclo. Primero debes determinar si estás logueado y despues llamar a `state.go`. La forma de hacer esto es almacenar un valor en una variable y modificarla **si estas logueado**. Luego que termine el ciclo comparas con la variable **y entonces** navegas.

Comment: Ya pude arreglarle muchas gracias Sus consejos son muy buenos. Lo que he hecho ha sido implementar la 2da opcion.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes observar las rutas y las credenciales y redirigir a login si no esta autentificado

En tu **config** puedes cambiar

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

por

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/usuario');
```

y en **run** agregar un observador

```
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
    var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;// aqui tu usuario logeado desde sqlLite
//si loggedIn es null o undefinid se enviara a la pagina login
    if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }
    });
```

De esta manera si no esta logeado siempre lo enviara a login.